# The signature '(config: ClientConfig): SanityClient' of 'sanityClient' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am getting this when I try to use sanityClient.
`The signature '(config: ClientConfig): SanityClient' of 'sanityClient' is deprecated.`

Here is how my connection looks like

```
export const client = sanityClient({
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2023-08-17',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as the error message says `'sanityClient' is deprecated`. You can use `@sanity/client` package to remove the warning.

First, install `@sanity/client` package:

```
npm install @sanity/client
```

And import it:

```
import {createClient} from '@sanity/client'
```

And you can use initiate it like you do before:

```
const client = createClient({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  dataset: 'your-dataset-name',
  useCdn: true, // set to `false` to bypass the edge cache
  apiVersion: '2023-05-03', // use current date (YYYY-MM-DD) to target the latest API version
  // token: process.env.SANITY_SECRET_TOKEN // Only if you want to update content with the client
})
```

All this guide, i take it from the official `@sanity/client` docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/client)